# Javascript API explorer / sandbox

Tags: documentation, api

Does anyone know of a simple API explorer that I can use to make a nice test page for my web service? I am aware of the following, and these are similar to what I want:

http://api-playground-demo.hipo.biz/

https://github.com/mashery/iodocs

But both of those fall down in some way - the Django one is close, but it only lets you send POST data as JSON, and I'm just using plain `multipart/form-data` key/value pairs. It is also a bit of a pain to set up as it requires Django, whereas really you should be able to do all of this as a static site in client-side javascript.

IODocs also has an insane list of requirements.

So ideally I'd like something very similar to the Django API playground, but with the following features:

- Can substitute variables into the GET parameters, *and* the URL. I.e. `http://foo.com/{variable1}/bar?q={variable2}`
- Lets me send play form-encoded POST data, instead of (or in addition to) JSON
- Doesn't have any ridiculous server-side dependencies.
- Ideally, lets me send files.
- Ideally, lets me send custom headers which include variables, e.g. `X-Auth-Code: {variable3}`

Surely someone must have done this?

Answer (score 0):

Found [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) which with some minor adjustments does everything I want, including sending files and custom headers.

The only thing I had to fix was a small bug where optional POST fields are sent with the value "undefined" instead of being omitted entirely (or being sent as empty strings).